# Windows Phone 8.1 Versioning Package Upload Error

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, package, updates, windows-store

I want to create App Packages to update my beta app in the Windows Phone store. I've already done it a 100 times, and there was no problem. But now I get this error:

*The value of the Version attribute of the Identity element in the app manifest must have a higher version than 'MyLastUpdatePackage'*

The version I want to upload is 1.1.0.15, and the last upload is 1.1.0.14, so it's definitely greater. What may cause the problem?

Comment: Have you checked the version number at the dashboard in details? Maybe there is a mistake in numbering?

Comment: Yes, I checked it. No idea what's wrong :( Maybe it's a bug at Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have your account migrated to the new dev center dashboard? I'm getting errors since that happened and also found other people complaining about it. Check these two threads:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/81fcb869-6e0e-4540-b72b-f9398b103d64/wpslcryptic-error-seen-while-trying-to-upgrade-wp8-app

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/0e049549-ab15-4211-9e63-2534f595e45a/wpslfailure-to-update-app-in-the-store

Comment: No, I didn't migrate to the new dashboard. Thanks for replying, but I ended up submitting as a new beta app, instead of updating.